# How to do per field facet min count in solr query using java?

Tags: solr, solrj

In solr document it is written: 
The facet.mincount parameter specifies the minimum counts required for a facet field to be included in the response. If a field's counts are below the minimum, the field's facet is not returned.
The default value is 0.
This parameter can be specified on a per-field basis with the syntax of **f.fieldname.facet.mincount.**

How to do this in java? I don't see a query.setMinCount for a field only for the overall query.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/query/FacetOptions.html

Comment: Doesn't `setFacetMinCount` in the documentation you linked work?

Answer (score 3):

In java I'm used to use SolrJ directly, without Spring or other frameworks.

I suggest `SolrQuery`, which is the class used commonly to prepare query parameters.

As you have seen there are many many parameters when you prepare a Solr query, but, even with SolrJ, not all the parameters have an equivalent method.

Given that, there is no method for `f.fieldname.facet.mincount` parameter.

But `SolrQuery` has a method `add` inherited by its parent `ModifiableSolrParams`. You can use this method to figure out every case not handled by standard `SolrQuery` interface.

For example this query add a :

```
SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery()
q.setQuery("*:*")
q.setFacet(true);
q.addFacetField("country");
q.add("f.country.facet.mincount", "1");
```

Consider that, if you want, you can use even only the add method:

```
SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery()
q.add("q", "*:*")
q.add("facet", "true");
q.add("facet.field", "country");
q.add("f.country.facet.mincount", "1");
```

On the other hand, if you want try to use Spring, well, looking at `FacetOptions` class I see there is a nested static class `FacetOptions.FacetParameter` that have a costructor `FacetOptions.FacetParameter(String parameter, Object value)`, which it seems to accept every kind of parameter/value. In some way `FacetParameter` resembles the behaviour we have just seen with SolrJ `add` method.